# hover drop down menu disappears before I can click on it

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, mousehover

I have a few buttons appear under my posts. One of those buttons is a social share button and when you hover over it a social share menu appears. The problem is I can't get to the menu because it disappears once my mouse is off of the main share button. I have a margin of 30px so I'm assuming this is causing the problem. However I do not know how to fix it because I want that margin of 30px. Does anyone have any solutions?

here is a rough fiddle (doesn't look exactly like mine but you get the idea) - https://jsfiddle.net/8e3459g6/

how mine actually looks when you hover over share button -

[image]

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <img class="main-share button" src="http://amandoblogs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/share-e1408475480528.png" />

  <div class="share-buttons">

    <a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=Love this post by @ <?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Tweet this!"><img src="https://www.theclimategroup.org/sites/all/modules/custom/tcg_social_media_icons/icons/black/16x16/twitter.png"></a>

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://www.shipwreckmuseum.com/wp-content/themes/shipwreckmuseum/assets/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook" />
    </a>

    <a href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());">
      <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-FaD4j4FL1Bc/TuEf9aN1gEI/AAAAAAAABek/kVqztZRwJ1w/s128/Pinterest_Favicon.png" alt="Pinterest" />
    </a>

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://www.ihatestevensinger.com/osafe_theme/images/user_content/images/icon-heart.png" alt="Heart" />
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

```html
.wrap:hover .share-buttons {
      display:block;
  position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left:-34px;
}
.wrap:hover .triangle-share {
      display:block;
  position: absolute;
 white-space: nowrap;

}
.share-buttons {
  display: none;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    padding:10px 20px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
.main-share-button {

}
.triangle-share {
border-bottom: 12px solid #efefef;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
margin-top:18px;
    margin-left:8px;
  content: "";
  display: none;
}
.wrap {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your Snippet it looks nothing like the included image nor does it function as you've described.

Comment: It still has the same issue. When you hover over share button the menu appears. But because of the padding once your mouse moves off of the share button the menu dissapears.

Comment: try using `margin-top: -5px;` in your  **share-buttons** css class

Answer (score 0):

You can add an offset until your menu disappears . A small one like 100 ms and you cleat it when the mouse hovers over the menu .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the mouse out event is being triggered before the sub menu gets a chance to display. Would it work to remove that margin-top and replace it with a padding-bottom of 30px on the parent menu?

Comment: This works at not having the menu disappear when your mouse is off of main button. However, the main button is now now aligned with the other buttons and has moved up.

Comment: Ok. Could you posr a screen shot? Or a new fiddle?